# Multiple Recursion statement calls

Tags: c, recursion, quicksort

```
void quickSort(int *a, int beg, int end)
{                       
  int pivotLoc;

  if (beg < end)
  {         
    partitionArray(a, beg, end, &pivotLoc);       
    quickSort(a, beg, pivotLoc - 1); 
    quickSort(a, pivotLoc + 1, end);
  } 
}
```

When is 2nd recursion statement called?

When is 1st recursion statement exited?

I'm having big time confusion in multiple recursion statement calls.

Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: Please indent your code properly!

Comment: Grab pencil and paper and trace the function calls and stack frames to see what is called and when.

Comment: I'm doing that past 1 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a small example to understand the recursion now.

Say you call `quickSort` on the following array as:

```
int a = {3,1,4,2,5};
quickSort(a,0,4);
```

Now, let's start tracing.

1. First you'll have a call to `quickSort(a,0,4)`.
2. This call then declares a local variable `pivotLoc`.
3. Then you check for the condition `beg<end` where `beg = 0` and `end = 4` (as you passed them in step 1).
4. Now you call a function called `partitionArray(a,0,4,address_of_pivotLoc);`
5. Upon returning of `partitionArray` function, the value of `pivotLoc` variable has been set.
6. Now you call `quickSort(a, 0, pivotLoc-1)` which again repeat from step one EXCEPT the `end` is **not** 4, but is `pivotLoc-1`.

> When is 2nd recursion statement called?

Answer : When the condition `beg<end` fails in the first recursive call, it'll just return. This is the time the second recursive call starts executing from the *last* call of the first recursion (i.e. from the last call where the first recursion *didn't* fail the condition `beg<end`).

> When is 1st recursion statement exited?

Answer : When it fails the condition `beg<end`, it'll reach the end of it's function and return to the previous call of the *same* function. Then the second recursive call starts.

TLDR; Basically the condition that makes **any** of the `quickSort` calls to end is the `if` condition `beg<end`.

Comment: Oh God. This helped me so much. Thanks a lot. It is very much clear now

Comment: Wait, just found this post : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/ , extemely useful trace.

Answer (score 1):

The question can be generalised:

```
void f()
{
    f() // 0
    f() // 1
    // ...
    f() // n
}
```

If we draw a call graph from, we (of course) get a tree-like structure:

```
               f()
        /     /      \
    /(0)    /(1)  ....  \(n)
f()       f()               f()
```

Each further recursive call will repeat above tree below the respective parent call. The tree does not need to be balanced, i. e. paths from root to the different leaves can vary in length. If the recursive calls are inside a conditional branch, not even all non-leave nodes need to have the same number of children.

Now, if we have two arbitrary function calls `f(); g();` following one another, `g` can only be called when `f()` returns. This applies, of course, as well for two subsequent recursive calls, which in turn implies, that the call tree necessarily is walked like in depth-first-search.

Coming back to your quicksort example (and ignoring for simplicity that partitioning does not need to result in two equal sized halves), then second half of each sub array will only be sorted as soon as the previous half is completed. Seen globally:

```
sort first half
  sort first quarter
    sort first eighth
    sort second eighth
  sort second quarter
    sort third eighth
    sort fourth eighth
sort second half
  sort third quarter
      // ...
  sort fourth quarter
      // ...
```